# 3 Wrong Root Password Attempt --> Logout

Tags: login, root

Can I implement a protocol so that if you input the wrong root password 3 times, you are not allowed to try again until you restart your computer? Or even shutdown the computer then email the owner that someone attempted to log in as root 3 times?

Comment: No, but you can lock the user: https://askubuntu.com/questions/338588/limit-user-login-attempts-ubuntu-12-10-pam-tally-so-pam-tally2-so and https://askubuntu.com/questions/59459/how-do-i-enable-account-lockout-using-pam-tally and https://linux-audit.com/locking-users-after-failed-login-attempts-with-pam_tally2/ Make sure not to lockout your only admin.

Comment: By the way: if you do not trust a user to be admin why trust them with sudo powers to start with? Set up a restricted user and grant powers to commands it needs with sudo and block anything else seems the more easier approach.

Comment: It is not that I don't trust an admin. I am just trying to finish/work on a project I set out to do. And thank you for responding so fast.

Comment: Can you say "denial of service"?

Comment: @waltinator, as asked, this would not likely lead to a DoS scenario. If the system automatically reboots itself and unlocks the accounts at the same time, at worst the authorized user would come back to a system that has tallied two failed attempts and will only reboot if the authorized user fails on his/her first login attempt. Of course the implications of a locked system being rebooted with files in an unsaved state should be considered, but it could be argued that that's outside the scope of DoS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends! If your login greeter honors what is in the pam.d common-auth file, then you can...

Open your common-auth file for editing `sudo nano /etc/pam.d/common-auth`. Add the following two lines at the very top.

```
auth    required    pam_tally.so    onerr=fail deny=3
account required    pam_tally.so    reset
```

*(there may be better configuration options for common-auth, but this seems to work; I'd be willing to edit if someone can improve)*

To reset the account locks at reboot, edit root's crontab with `sudo crontab -e` and add the following line at the bottom:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/faillog -a -r
```

If you want to send an email, then perhaps it would be best to make a script to run at boot (via root's crontab) that accomplishes everything you want rather than running the command above with root's crontab. The script would look something like this...

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Do check to see if specific account is locked
user=NAME_OF_ACCT_TO_CHECK
failCount=$(faillog -u $user | grep -P "^$user" | awk '{print $2}')

if [ $failCount -ge 3 ]; then
# send your email
# do whatever else you want to do when account is locked
fi

# reset counts
faillog -a -r
```

Comment: I just reread your question. If you want to reboot after three failed attempts, you would have to set up a script to watch the output of `faillog -u $user` where $user is the user you want to watch. When your script sees that the threshold has been exceeded, it could send an email and reboot the system automatically. My answer above won't reboot the system when the threshold is reached, which is marginally more secure since someone attempting to guess a password might not  reboot the system. Thus the account remains in a locked state until the system is actually rebooted.