# Is there a GUI or package that you can install to enforce password policies?

Tags: password, gui

Things like Minimum length and Captial Letters. Along with Lockout policies. If there isnt a GUI, how would you complete this using command prompt. (Password History, Max password age, Min password age, Min length, Numb Cap, Numb Special, Numb Number, Reversible encryption, Lockout duration, Lockout threshold, Lockout reset time)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enforce a password complexity policy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244115/how-do-i-enforce-a-password-complexity-policy) And https://askubuntu.com/questions/59459/how-do-i-enable-account-lockout-using-pam-tally for the locking

Answer (score 2):

Of course, password policies can be adapted in linux. Some options may be exposed depending on the desktop environments you use, although there may be no extensive GUI that exposes all possible options.

In the system file `/etc/login.defs`, you can define minimum length of the password, how long a password is valid, how long it takes before being able to enter a new password after having entered a wrong password, etc. Consult `man login.defs` for all options.

You can also check password history, where the system will check whether a new password you use has been entered before. That is set in the `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` system file.

Finally, you can control the requirements for the password string itself in the file /etc/pam.d/common-password. This functionality is provided by `libpam-pwquality`, which is installed by default in Ubuntu.